# stdlib.hが見つからない？

Tags: raspberry-pi, gcc, qt5

RaspberryPi3上のQt5で、外部ライブラリを使いたいのですが、エラーで上手く行きません。
wiringPiと言うライブラリを、aptでインストール後、

Qt5の、プロジェクトファイル .pro　に以下を追加し
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include
LIBS += -L /usr/lib -l wiringPi

ビルドすると、以下のエラーが出ます。

```
/usr/include/c++/8/bits/stl_algo.h:59:
/usr/include/c++/8/algorithm:62:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:142:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtGui/qtguiglobal.h:43:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets/qtwidgetsglobal.h:43:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h:43:
/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/QtWidgets/QMainWindow:1:
/home/pi/Qt/illumination/mainwindow.h:4:
/home/pi/Qt/illumination/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/8/cstdlib:75:
 エラー: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
```

え、include_next って何？

stdlib.hを検索してみると、以下の様になっています。
root@Rasbian://# find -name stdlib.h

```
./opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/SystemFiles/Links/ArduinoLink/Resources/CSource/avr-libc/1.8.1/avr/include/stdlib.h
./usr/include/c++/8/tr1/stdlib.h
./usr/include/c++/8/stdlib.h
./usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bits/stdlib.h
./usr/include/stdlib.h
```

また、wiringPi関連のヘッダは

```
wiringPi.h  
wiringPiI2C.h  
wiringPiSPI.h  
wiringSerial.h  
wiringShift.h
```

のようなのですが、この中で stdlib.hを呼んでいる箇所は無いようなのです。

何が問題なのかも分かりません。
よろしく、お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make` (または `cmake`) 実行時、以下のパラメータを追加してみてください。

```
$ make -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF
```

参考:
[Error compiling OpenCV, fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40271452)

Comment: Make argments: に　-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF と追加すると、確かに一度はビルドできたんですが、色々いじって検証していたら、今は　:-1: エラー: invalid option -- 'D'　でビルドできなくなってしまいました？？？

Comment: G++自体の問題だったようで、apt-get updateで解決でしました。